# Angular CLI build dist without updating modified time of assets (e.g. images)

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

Is there a way to tell the Angular 4 CLI to copy assets into the dist folder without updating the file modified date/time?

My deployment app copies all files changed, and since all the files in assets folder get a new modified date/time it ends up copying everything every time - including a load of images and docs that never change.

I am considering moving the assets folder out of the project and copying them separately because of this, but that bugs me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use automated scripts for deployment where you run the copy command that modifies the timestaps. Consider replacing a regular copy command with the utility that has an option to keep original timestamps.

For example, you can find the package fs-extra on npmjs.org that has an option preserveTimestamps. There is also a wrapper fs-extra-cli for this package that allows you to run this utility from the command line: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra-cli

This should do the trick.

Comment: I use `ng build --prod` to build the app in the /dist folder. The `.angular-cli.json` config tells it which assets to copy to the /dist/assets folder. It is not obvious to me right now how fs-extra can integrate with the angular build process.

Comment: You need to get familiar with npm script. You can create your own build command that will run the utilities you need. In this presentation I explained how to create custom deployment scripts https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=2238

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by modifying the Angular **v14** build code directly. I then persisted this change to my codebase using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

This is the resulting patch code, which includes the filename `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/copy-assets.js`

The two lines I added use `fs.statSync` to read the timestamps from the original and then use `fs.utimesSync` to write them to the copied file.

```
@@ -1,3 +1,17 @@
+diff --git a/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/copy-assets.js b/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/copy-assets.js
+index 2eb79a8..ed1f9f1 100644
+--- a/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/copy-assets.js
++++ b/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/utils/copy-assets.js
+@@ -69,6 +69,9 @@ async function copyAssets(entries, basePaths, root, changed) {
+                     directoryExists.add(dir);
+                 }
+                 fs.copyFileSync(src, dest, fs.constants.COPYFILE_FICLONE);
++                // This patch added so that copied assets retain their original createdAt/updatedAt timestamps, which will improve browser caching and deployments
++                const stat = fs.statSync(src);
++                fs.utimesSync(dest, stat.atime, stat.mtime)
+             }
+         }
+     }
```